# Flutter web cannot use packages from mobile project

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

A few months ago I made an android application using flutter. The application requires various dependencies such as intl, cached network image, stopper, carousel_slider, etc.

Then right now I want to convert the project to flutter_web. Here are the steps that I did:

1. clone github web flutter
2. I run the command "flutter packages pub global activate webdev"
3. Then I edited pubspec.yaml and I adjusted it to pubspec.yaml in the previous project (android project)

Here is the contents of pubspec.yaml on the web flutter project:

```
name: flutter_web.examples.hello_world

environment:
  # You must be using Flutter> = 1.5.0 or Dart> = 2.3.0
  sdk: '> = 2.3.0-dev.0.1 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter_web: any
  flutter_web_ui: any
  stopper: ^ 1.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^ 1.4.0
  build_web_compilers: ^ 2.0.0

dependency_overrides:
  flutter_web:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages / flutter_web
  flutter_web_ui:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages / flutter_web_ui
  provider:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/kevmoo/provider
      ref: flutter_web
```

When I run 'pub dev', an error occurs while resolving the package stopper. Then I tried to open github from the package stopper (https://github.com/aryzhov/flutter-stopper), after that I checked the files in the lib folder. There I found a file called stopper.dart. It turns out that in the file, still using
 import 'package: flutter / material.dart';
So that makes my pubspec error. Because the code should be replaced with
import 'package: flutter_web / material.dart';

Therefore, I tried to outsmart the problem by removing the dependency stopper on pubspec.yaml, then I created a stopper.dart file manually, then I saved it in the lib/mypackages folder. After that, I import stopper.dart from the lib/mypackages folder (it's no longer through the package).

The package stopper is just one of the packages that I use on my Android project. Actually there are many other packages that have the same problem as the package stopper. The point is I have to create the package files manually, then I change "package: flutter / ..." to "package: flutter_web /" manually, then I can import them.

What I want to ask, is there a more elegant and simple way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi the instruction you are following is from an old repository [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web). As you can see this is discontinued. You can find the informaiton in the REadme.

Instead you should follow the instructions in this [page](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web#enable-web-support). Read it once carefully and I would suggest to keep a backup of your main project and work on a copy.

1. First you will have to enable the flutter-web using `flutter config --enable-web`.
2. Then you will have to run `flutter create .`